# How we can set our own colors for each label in charts

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I am using [angularjs charts](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/).
The colors are coming in sequence, but I want to define color for each label as my own choice, because color meaniing matters for user.

**For Example:** I want colors as:

- "Completed": GREEN
- "In Progress": YELLOW
- "Not started": RED.

  So how can I do this with the JS I am using.
  Hope you got my problem. Expecting help or suggestion(s).

Sample data, I am using:

```
$scope.labels = ["Completed", "In Progress", "Not started"];
$scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
```

Simple Display Chart:

```
 <canvas  id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true"
                      click="onClick" hover="onHover" series="series"></canvas>
```

**Note:** All is fine with the current Chart display, Only I want to implement *Color choice* manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply an array of objects with attributes `strokeColor` for regular color and `pointHighlightStroke` for mouseover color to the `colours` s
attribute of canvas.

```
$scope.colours = [
    {strokeColor : "#FF00FF", pointHighlightStroke : "#FF00AA"},
    {strokeColor : "#00FFFF", pointHighlightStroke : "#00FFAA"},
    {strokeColor : "#FFFF00", pointHighlightStroke : "#FFAA00"}
];
```

An your HTML

```
<canvas  id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" colours="colours"></canvas>
```

Now your pie slices and legend are displayed in the colors that you've chosen. 
For Tooltip colors you should check [Custom Tooltip documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-external-tooltips) of Chart.js

Comment: Thanks. How can we add effects (like zoom-in, zoom-out) on mouseover instead of changing colors?

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem:

```
$scope.labels = ["Completed", "In Progress", "Not started"];
$scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
$scope.lbl_colors = ['#33CC33', '#FFFF66', '#FF3300'];
```

HTML:

```
<canvas  id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true"
  click="onClick" hover="onHover" series="series" colours="lbl_colors" ></canvas>
```